# Pandas datrafame inconsistent data in mulitple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have something like that:

```
>>> x = {'id': [1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5], 'value': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(x)
>>> df
   id value
0   1     a
1   1     a
2   2     b
3   2     b
4   2     c
5   3     d
6   4     e
7   5     f
8   5     g
```

I want to filter inconsistent values in this table. For example, columns with `id=2` or `id=5` are inconsistent, because the same `id` is associated with different values. I have read solutions about `where` or `any`, but they are not something like "comparing if columns with this `id` always have the same `value`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you want to with these values? Remove them? Can you provide an expected output

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining well what I wanted as output. I wanted something like Allen answered - to get the problematic id's. But I liked the solution with drop_duplication too, so, thanks, Mayank! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use groupby and filter. This should give you the ids with inconsistent values.

```
df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: x.value.nunique()>1)

    id  value
2   2   b
3   2   b
4   2   c
7   5   f
8   5   g
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case we do `groupby` + `transform` with `nunique`

```
unc_df=df[df.groupby('id').value.transform('nunique').ne(1)]
   id value
2   2     b
3   2     b
4   2     c
7   5     f
8   5     g
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you can use **[`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)** to drop repetitive rows based on `id` column:

```
In [599]: df.drop_duplicates('id', keep='first')    
Out[599]: 
   id value
0   1     a
2   2     b
5   3     d
6   4     e
7   5     f
```

So the above will pick the first `value` for duplicated `id` column. And you will have 1 row per id in your resultant dataframe.